# Eating non-kosher food without swallowing?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, eating

We find several places in which you would be liable for eating non-kosher food.

Let’s say someone placed the non-kosher food in their mouth, began to chew, but did not swallow. Would they be liable for eating non-kosher?

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/21598 https://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/3-When-is-a-Bracha-Not-Required.html

Comment: When you chew food in your mouth then spit it out, some of it will have dissolved and you will swallow it, willingly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pischei Teshuva 98: 1 writes about this :

יטעמנו עובד כוכבים. עבה"ט בשם ט"ז. וע"ל סי' מ"ב בבה"ט סק"ג שכתב בשם הש"ך דלהכי גבי מרה שרי לטעום דקרוב הדבר שיטעום טעם מר ע"ש משמע דאי לאו הכי אף טעימה בלשון אסור וכ"כ הפמ"ג בסי' צ"ה במשבצות ס"ק ט"ו דהכי קי"ל ואסור ללחוך בלשון אם מלוח ע"ש.ועיין בשו"ת צמח צדק סי' מ"ז שנשאל אם מותר לטעום הבורית אם יש בו מלח כל צרכו והשיב דאע"ג דדבר שהוא פגום. מדרבנן מיהא אסור לכתחלה וטעימה היינו דוקא לאכילה אבל לטעימה שרי לכתחלה וטעימה אינו אסור אלא מדרבנן ובדרבנן לא גזרו ע"ש. והמובן מדבדה"ה בכל איסורי דרבנן שרי טעימה ואף לטעום בפיו ממש וכן הבין בנו של בעל צ"צ בסוף הספר והפר"ח בסי' ק"ח ס"ק כ"ב ע"ש (ועפ"ז מיושב דברי רש"י בחולין ד' צ"ז ע"ב במה שפירש דאיסורא כגון בשר בחלב שאין ישראל יכול לטועמו ע"ש וגם אפשר לתרץ קושיית התוס' שם ע"א בד"ה אבלבב"ח מהא דיין במים כו' אמנם התוס' לשיטתייהו בדף צ"ח ע"ב בד"ה רבא דחולקים על רש"י ז"ל וס"ל דאף רבא ס"ל בכל האיסורים טעם כעיקר דאורייתא ע"ש ודו"ק) אכן בתשובת נו"ב תניינא חיו"ד סי' נ"ב כתב דהצ"צ לא התיר אלא טעימה בלשון ומסיק דאף טעימה בלשון אינו מותר כי אם באיסור פגום ולא בכל איסורי דרבנן ע"ש

He brings different opinions (tasting gallbladder,tasting meat to see if salted) and seems to come out that we are stringent to even taste prohibited foods. Further in he brings the Tzemach Tzedek who brings a distinction between doraisa which is assur to taste even with ones tongue and derabbans(pegam)which tasting isn't part of gezeira may even be put in ones mouth. However,see how the Noda BeYehuda understands his shitta.

To answer the question, you would not be liable for eating non-kosher ,but rather there is a rabbanic prohibition to do so(see above for different distinctions made in the Pischei Teshuva).